# Why vba loop fails after the first round?

Tags: vba, loops, foreach

My code is suppose to create sheets, then charts on sheets with name "Sheet..." and then create a powerpoint. then it deletes all sheets and starts all over again. The charts creation part works, but when it comes to creating a powerpoint, the code hops over the IF-statement. It works the first round but after that it jumps over IF.

```
Dim ppt         As PowerPoint.Application
Set ppt = New PowerPoint.Application

ppt.Visible = msoTrue
```

'Change template source if necessary

```
ppt.Presentations.Open "C:\Desktop\Template\PowerPoint_Template.potx", _
Untitled:=msoTrue

ppt.Activate

Dim ppt_pres    As PowerPoint.Presentation
Set ppt_pres = ppt.ActivePresentation

Dim ppt_layout  As CustomLayout
Set ppt_layout = ppt_pres.Slides(2).CustomLayout

Dim ppt_slide   As PowerPoint.Slide
Set ppt_slide = ppt_pres.Slides.AddSlide(2, ppt_layout)

Dim ppt_shape   As PowerPoint.Shape
Set ppt_shape = ppt_slide.Shapes(1)

Dim ppw As Object
Set ppw = ppt_pres.Windows(ppt_pres.Windows.Count)

Dim wsPIA As Worksheet
Set wsPIA = Sheet4
```

'Naming title slide

```
ppt_pres.Slides(1).Shapes(3).TextFrame.TextRange.Text = wsPIA.Range("C2") 
ppt_pres.Slides(1).Shapes(2).TextFrame.TextRange.Text = wsPIA.Range("I2")
```

'Identifying number of sheets that contain newly created charts

```
Dim j As Integer, vNames() As Variant, ws As Worksheet, picture As Shape
j = 0
For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
If Left(ws.Name, 5) = "Sheet" Then
j = j + 1
ReDim Preserve vNames(j)
vNames(j) = ws.Name
End If
Next ws

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
```

'Looping copypaste of charts from excel to powerpoint

```
For Each ws In Worksheets

If Left(ws.Name, 5) = "Sheet" Then
    ws.Select

    For Each picture In ActiveSheet.Shapes
            picture.Copy

        ppw.View.GotoSlide ppt_pres.Slides.Count - 1

            ppt_slide.Shapes.PasteSpecial ppPasteEnhancedMetafile

        ppt_slide.Shapes(7).Height = 390
        ppt.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Align msoAlignCenters, msoCTrue
        ppt.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Align msoAlignMiddles, msoTrue
        ppt_slide.Shapes(7).Top = ppt_slide.Shapes(7).Top + 14
        ppt_slide.Shapes.Title.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = wsPIA.Range("C2")
        ppt_slide.Shapes(4).TextFrame.TextRange.Text =wsPIA.Range("I2")


        ppw.View.GotoSlide ppt_pres.Slides.Count - 1


Set ppt_slide = ppt_pres.Slides.AddSlide(ppt_pres.Slides.Count - 1, ppt_layout)



    Next

End If

Next
```

'Deleting blank slides from the end

```
ppt_pres.Slides.item(ppt_pres.Slides.Count - 1).Delete
ppt_pres.Slides.item(ppt_pres.Slides.Count - 1).Delete

With ppt_pres
.SaveAs ("C:\Desktop\Presentations\Pres1.pptx")
.Close

End With
```

The first round, line:

If Left(ws.Name, 5) = "Sheet" Then ws. Select

is true but after the first iteration, it skips that and goes straight to

'Deleting blank slides from the end

Comment: How many sheets satisfy this condition ? You condition looks right to me. Also, try after removing the next line `ws.Select` you don't need it. Replace `Activesheet` with `ws` in line `Activesheet.Shapes` I think this is the Issue

Comment: I have 12 sheets right now. The first round they are "Sheet1", "Sheet2" etc. and the second round "Sheet13", "Sheet14", "Sheet15" etc.

Comment: I tried it and it still skips over the IF-statement.

Comment: Try running the code in Debugging mode using `F8` and see what is the value of `ws.name` in each iteration.